# Hibernate mysql groupe by day concequetive results

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have this function

i need to do that in sql (hibernate or mysql) or a java function that interpert the array of results

i need a consequetive results fort groupe by day

select DAY(prop.docCreationDate), count(prop.docfullName) from propCode.propClass as prop where prop.docCreationDate >= '" + startDate + " 00:00:00' and prop.docCreationDate <= '" + endDate + " 23:59:59' GROUP BY DAY(prop.docCreationDate)"

```
i have this entitie count in my table
2012-10-05   3
2012-10-06   0
2012-10-07   7
2012-10-08   13
2012-10-09   9
2012-10-10   0
2012-10-11   0
2012-10-12   3

the request return me this values
5    3
7    7
8    13
9    9
12   3

in this way i loose three lignes that have 0 as value, i need a request that return me this
5    3
6    0
7    7
8    13
9    9
10   0
11   0
12   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that in your `propClass` table you have multiple entries per day with document path names. Since the entries that you have provided are already almost what you need, except for a day conversion, and it's not matching the query used.

Considering this, the entries mentioned by you are the total number of documents per day and I assume that for the missing days you inserted the 0 values. If so, you can use `time_intervals` temporary table like the one mentioned [here](http://schimpf.es/generate-a-list-between-two-dates-in-mysql/). And then you should be able to do something like:

```
call interval_between('"+ startDate +"', '" + endDate + "', 'DAY', 1);

select day(ti.interval_from), count(prop.docfullName) from time_intervals ti left join propClass as prop 
on prop.docCreationDate>=ti.interval_from AND prop.docCreationDate < ti.interval_from + INTERVAL 1 DAY
where ti.interval_from>='"+ startDate +"' and ti.interval_from < '" + endDate + "'
group by ti.interval_from;
```

Using [native queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) you can call the above two statements from hibernate.

Tested with [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0461d/3).

Comment: @Touhami From hibernate you can use native queries for the above calls. See: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/